# How do I insert a member-function pointer into a map?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have this map:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<void (std::string)>> cMap;
```

I don't quite understand how to add value to it?

I tried

> cMap.insert(std::make_pair("test", &Manager::testfunc));

And

> cMap["test"] = &Manager::testfunc;

But I get "failed to specialize function template" errors on either one.

I'm not all that familiar with function pointers and I've honestly spent *hours* googling and reading questions and answers, but I just can't find anything that works. Please help me.

Edit:
For now, Manager::testfunc is just:

```
void Manager::testfunc (std::string value) { }
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of `Manager::testfunc`?

Comment: Did you try initializing an `std::function<std::string()>` from `&Manager::testfunc`?

Comment: @Brian - added. It's pretty much just a shell at the moment. I plan to add the code to it after I figure out how to get the map working.

Comment: @juanchopanza - how does that work? I don't really understand, sorry!

Comment: You should understand that before you try using maps of functions. One step at a time. It has nothing to do with maps.

Comment: @juanchopanza - It's just that testfunc is supposed to get it's string value from the map, and then do some actions based on that. I don't see how I can initialize values in that function when I don't yet know what the values are going to be. Am I making sense or is my explanation bad?

Comment: You aren't making any sense. Figure out how to use `std::function`.

Comment: `Manager::testfunc` is a `std::function<void (std::string)>` not a `std::function<std::string()>`

Comment: @WhiteViking - Thanks, I updated my code to show that!

Comment: `&Manager::testfunc` is a pointer-to-member, not a function pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for a member function pointer to be callable you must bind it to an object. Thus, provided a `Manager` object (e.g., `Manager m`) you can use `std::bind` to bind a member function (e.g., `void Manager::foo(std::string const&)`) and then insert it in your `std::map` as follows:

```
struct Manager {
  void foo(std::string const& str) { std::cout << str << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  std::map<std::string, std::function<void(std::string const&)>> cMap;
  Manager m;
  cMap.insert(std::make_pair("test", std::bind(&Manager::foo, &m, std::placeholders::_1)));
  cMap["test"]("Hello, world!");
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a58425499c168cf)